# Django return 404 error

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm learning how do RESTfull web services using django_rest_framework. I have this in urls.py :

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^tests/', 'Web_Services.views.test'),
)
```

ans I have a test function in views.py :

```
@api_view(['GET', 'POST'])
def test(request, format=None):
    return Response({'Test OK!'})
```

my problem is that what when I add /?format=xml or anything other than json to the url I get 404 error. Another question : I get `Assignment to reserved built-in symbol: format` warning. I know what's it means but it's not me who decided to call it `format`. What I must do to resolve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to your `settings.py`:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    ...your other DRF settings
    'DEFAULT_RENDERER_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.renderers.XMLRenderer',
        'rest_framework.renderers.JSONRenderer',
    )
}
```

See the relevant DRF documentation here:

http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/renderers#setting-the-renderers

A couple other things I can think...perhaps it's related to your url pattern not having `$`, can you try:

```
url(r'^tests/$', 'Web_Services.views.test'),
```

Also, make sure your data is valid JSON, try returning `["TestOK!]`. Note the double-quotes.

Do you have any other urlpatterns defined in the project?

Comment: It was the first thing I have done but it doesn't work!

Comment: Hmm, ok edited the answer, perhaps try the `$` at the end of your URL pattern?

Comment: Dang, looking at my api_views, I don't use `format=None` and it still works. See if that does it.

Comment: No, maybe I must create a serializer for xml? but it strange that it return 404 error normally it will execute the test function.

Comment: Ahh, I think it may be that your data is not valid JSON. try returning `["TestOK!]` Note the double-quotes

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51432/discussion-between-user230137-and-fiver)